# Returning one element of an object and creating a new array of this element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that returns an array of objects like this:

```
[ { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 53.43887641, -2.26581926 ] },
  { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 53.260671, -2.12337785 ] },
  { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 53.44815087, -2.22897913 ] },
  //more of the same...
```

My question is then how do I return just the coordinates and create a new array containing just the coordinates so that it looks like this instead:

```
[[ 53.43887641, -2.26581926 ],
 [ 53.260671, -2.12337785 ],
 [ 53.44815087, -2.22897913 ],
 // more of the same ...
```

I believe you can return a specific element of an object by doing `return { coordinates: coordinates }` but I am unsure how to work this into a for loop.

Comment: `arr = arr.map(obj => obj.coordinates);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
 var coordsObj = [{
   type: 'Point',
   coordinates: [53.43887641, -2.26581926]
 }, {
   type: 'Point',
   coordinates: [53.260671, -2.12337785]
 }, {
   type: 'Point',
   coordinates: [53.44815087, -2.22897913]
 }]

var coordAr = coordsObj.map(function(o) {
  return o.coordinates;
})

console.log(coordAr) // [[53.43887641, -2.26581926], [53.260671, -2.12337785], [53.44815087, -2.22897913]]
```

As per @Tushar's comments, you could use the `ES2015` form:

```
let coordAr = coordsObj.map(o => o.coordinates)
```

Comment: As I said in comment, arrow function can be used. `arr = arr.map(obj => obj.coordinates);`

Answer (score 0):

And if you really need to do it in a for loop (say, older browser support and you can't / won't use a shim or lodash):

```
var coordinates = [];
var points = // your starting object

var len = points.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++{
   coordinates.push(points[i].coordinates);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reference an object key (`coordinates`) to get its value (`[58.999,67.222]`), but since you have an array of objects, you'll need to loop through them to get each set of coordinates:

```
var coordinate_array = [];
for (var i=0; i < object_arr.length; i ++) {
    coordinate_array.push(object_arr[i]['coordinates']);
    // Can also do: coordinate_array.push(object_arr[i].coordinates);
}
```

In the above code, `object_arr` is your array of objects, and `object_arr[i]` is a single object in the array.

If you're using jQuery, you can do:

```
var coordinate_array = [];
$.each(object_arr, function(object) {
    coordinate_array.push(object.coordinates);
});
```